# Running Python script from Excel VBA Filepath Spaces

Tags: python, vba, excel

I'm trying to run a Python script from Excel using this VBA script.

```vb
Sub Plot()

ChDir "M:\Tools and Utilities\ColorScout\ColorScout Data Parser\src"
Shell "C:\Anaconda3\python.exe M:\Tools and Utilities\ColorScout\ColorScout Data Parser\src\Main.py", vbNormalFocus

End Sub
```

Pretty basic.

However, it's failing on the second line. I get an error message from Python that M:\Tools is not a directory.

What I think is happening is that the spaces in "Tools and Utilities" aren't being recognized. How can I get Python to recognizes Tools and Utilities as a directory? Putting Tools and Utilities in quotation marks raises a syntax error in VBA.

Hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Try including the full parameter in quotations: `"C:\Anaconda3\python.exe ""M:\Tools and Utilities\...\Main.py"""`

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I'll provide an answer as a reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the full parameter in quotations:

```vb
Shell "C:\Anaconda3\python.exe ""M:\Tools and Utilities\...\Main.py"""
```